# html stop iframe pushing content down

Tags: html, css

i have a button that show / hides iframe.
however when the iframe is shown pushes content downwards.

How do i fix this? ive tried doing it with flexbox, with no sucess, probably to do with lack of skill.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and share your code? What is the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Normally that is set by making the element in question to be `position:absolute;` using CSS. Something like this:

```
.YourClassName {
position: absolute;
}
```

If you provide a link to your issue we can give you exact CSS.